# Documentation for embedding flurry code in BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry, flurry

I would like to know if there is any documentation for implementing flurry in a BlackBerry app. I just have the jar file and have no knowledge of coding the same. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FlurryAgent.onStartApp(yourKey);` - When app is launched

`FlurryAgent.onPauseApp();` - When app goes into background

`FlurryAgent.onDestroyApp();` - When app is closed

```
Hashtable fl = new Hashtable();
fl.put(someKey, someValue);
FlurryAgent.onEvent(someEventTitle, fl);
```

-- When you would like to store info about an event. For instance, search terms, location used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The basic informations are available in the download zip of flurry itself.